# How to get information of a specific Wikidata ID using SPARQL query?

Tags: sparql, wikidata

I know how to find all movies in Wikidata. So, I get a list of IDs like "Q18644475". If I try to get all film info for every film in the database in one query, I get a timeout. So, I decided to get the film info in individual queries.

Is there an SPARQL query to get the title and release year(optionally all possible info) for this ID?

Comment: `SELECT ?p ?o WHERE {<URI_OF_YOUR_FILM> ?p ?o }` doesn't work for you?

Comment: @AKSW you mean like this `SELECT ?p ?o WHERE {<https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q18644475> ?p ?o }` ?

Comment: More or less, but you have to use the correct entity URI, not the web page rendering URL. That means only `http` and not `https` and `/entity/` instead of `/wiki/`: `SELECT ?p ?o WHERE {<http://www.wikidata.org/entity/Q18644475> ?p ?o }`

Comment: @AKSW I tried to modify the query so I would see the data in human readable form: `SELECT ?p ?o ?pLabel ?oLabel WHERE {<http://www.wikidata.org/entity/Q18644475> ?p ?o SERVICE wikibase:label {     
        bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en" .
    }}` But all I get is URLs. Is there a way to get actual data and not URL's?

Comment: You have to scroll down. You're getting human-readable labels for the "non-meta" properties.

Comment: `PREFIX entity: <http://www.wikidata.org/entity/>

SELECT ?propUrl ?propLabel ?valUrl ?valLabel ?picture
WHERE
{
 entity:Q18644475 ?propUrl ?valUrl .
  ?property ?ref ?propUrl .
  ?property rdf:type wikibase:Property .
  ?property rdfs:label ?propLabel .
 
   ?valUrl rdfs:label ?valLabel
 FILTER (LANG(?valLabel) = 'en') .
 OPTIONAL{ ?valUrl wdt:P18 ?picture .}
 FILTER (lang(?propLabel) = 'en' )
}
ORDER BY ?propUrl ?valUrl`

Answer (score 4):

I find the hoops you have to jump through to use an entity ID in SPARQL to be quite nuts.

If anyone else stumbles across this question then an alternative is to download the complete entity information in JSON format.

For example:
https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Special:EntityData/Q18644475.json

Comment: Can you get only the label and the description from the JSON? Downloading all the data from an entity can take quite some time for some entries (Specially if you have to fetch tens of them)